# Ignore zeros and NAs in cumsum

Tags: r

I need to assign numbers to sets of consecutive values in every column and create new columns. Eventually I want to find a sum of values in z column that correspond to the first consecutive numbers in each column.

My data looks something like this:

```r
library(dplyr)

y1 = c(1,2,3,8,9,0)

y2 = c(0,0,0,4,5,6)

z = c(200,250,200,100,90,80)

yabc <- tibble(y1, y2, z)

# A tibble: 6 × 3
     y1    y2     z
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0   200
2     2     0   250
3     3     0   200
4     8     4   100
5     9     5    90
6     0     6    80
```

I tried the following formula:

```r
yabc %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("y")),
            list(mod = ~ cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(.x)!=1))+1))
```

that gave me the following result:

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 5
     y1    y2     z y1_mod y2_mod
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1     0   200      1      1
2     2     0   250      1      2
3     3     0   200      1      3
4     8     4   100      2      4
5     9     5    90      2      4
6     0     6    80      3      4
```

I am only interested in numbers greater than zero. I tried replacing zeros with `NA`, but it did not work either.

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 5
     y1    y2     z y1_mod y2_mod
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1    NA   200      1      1
2     2    NA   250      1     NA
3     3    NA   200      1     NA
4     8     4   100      2     NA
5     9     5    90      2     NA
6    NA     6    80     NA     NA
```

What I would like the data to look like is:

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 5

     y1    y2     z y1_mod y2_mod
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1     0   200      1      NA
2     2     0   250      1      NA
3     3     0   200      1      NA
4     8     4   100      2      1
5     9     5    90      2      1
6     0     6    80      NA     1
```

Is there any way to exclude zeros and start applying the formula only when `.x` is greater than 0? Or any other way to make the formula work the way I need? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO, Dariga! FYI, formatting questions can be cumbersome, certainly. I will suggest an edit shortly, if you don't like it you can always revert the changes. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189 for good pointers; for one, code *blocks* tend to read and format better when more than simple code expressions, and are defined by indentation (4+ spaces) or by using code "fences" *on their own line*, as in `\`\`\`\ny1=...\n\`\`\``.

Answer (score 3):

FYI: `mutate_at` has been superseded by `across`, I'll demonstrate the new method in my code.

```r
yabc %>%
  mutate(
    across(starts_with("y"),
      list(mod = ~ if_else(.x > 0,
                           cumsum(.x > 0 & c(FALSE, diff(.x) != 1)) + 1L,
                           NA_integer_) )
    )
  )
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#      y1    y2     z y1_mod y2_mod
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <int>  <int>
# 1     1     0   200      1     NA
# 2     2     0   250      1     NA
# 3     3     0   200      1     NA
# 4     8     4   100      2      2
# 5     9     5    90      2      2
# 6     0     6    80     NA      2
```

If this is sufficient (you don't care if it's `1` or `2` for the first effective group in `y2_mod`), then you're good. If you want to reduce them all to be 1-based, then

```r
yabc %>%
  mutate(
    across(starts_with("y"),
      list(mod = ~ if_else(.x > 0,
                           cumsum(.x > 0 & c(FALSE, diff(.x) != 1)),
                           NA_integer_))),
    across(ends_with("_mod"),
      ~ if_else(is.na(.x), .x, match(.x, na.omit(unique(.x))))
  )
)
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#      y1    y2     z y1_mod y2_mod
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <int>  <int>
# 1     1     0   200      1     NA
# 2     2     0   250      1     NA
# 3     3     0   200      1     NA
# 4     8     4   100      2      1
# 5     9     5    90      2      1
# 6     0     6    80     NA      1
```

Notes:

- `if_else` is helpful to handle the `NA`-including rows specially; it requires the same class, which can be annoying/confusing. Because of this, we need to pass the specific "class" of `NA` as the `false=` (third) argument to `if_else`. For example, `cumsum(.)+1` produces a `numeric`, so the third arg would need to be `NA_real_` (since the default `NA` is actually `logical`). Another way to deal with it is to either use `cumsum(.)+1L` (produces an integer) and `NA_integer_` or (as I show in my second example) use `cumsum(.)` by itself (and `NA_integer_`) since we `match` things later (and `match(.)` returns `integer`)
- I demo the shift from your `mutate_at` to `mutate(across(..))`. An important change here from `mutate` is that we run `across` without assigning its return to anything. In essence, it returns a named-list where each element of the list is an updated column or a new one, depending on the presence of `.names`; that takes a `glue`-like string to allow for renaming the calculated columns, thereby *adding* new columns instead of the default action (no `.names`) of overwriting the columns in-place. The alternate way of producing new (not in-place) columns is the way you used, with a named list of functions, still a common/supported way to use a list of functions within `across(..)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

yabc %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('y'),
           ~ as.integer(factor(`is.na<-`(rleid(.x - row_number()), !.x))), 
           .names = '{col}_mod'))
    
# A tibble: 6 x 5
     y1    y2     z y1_mod y2_mod
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <int>  <int>
1     1     0   200      1     NA
2     2     0   250      1     NA
3     3     0   200      1     NA
4     8     4   100      2      1
5     9     5    90      2      1
6     0     6    80     NA      1
```

The trick lies in knowing that for consecutive numbers, the difference between the number and their row_number() is the same:

ie consider:

```
 x <- c(1,2,3,6,7,8,10,11,12)
```

The consecutive numbers can be grouped as:

```
 x - seq_along(x)
 [1] 0 0 0 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

As you can see, the consecutive numbers are grouped together. To get the desired groups, we should use `rle`

```
rleid(x-seq_along(x))
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

y1=c(1,2,3,8,9,0)
y2=c(0,0,0,4,5,6)
z=c(200,250,200,100,90,80)
yabc<-tibble(y1,y2,z)

yabc %>% 
 mutate(across(starts_with("y"),
  ~if_else(.x==0, NA_real_, 1+cumsum(c(1,diff(.x)) != 1)), .names="{.col}_mod"))%>% 
 mutate(across(ends_with("mod"), ~ factor(.x) %>% as.numeric(.)))

#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#>      y1    y2     z y1_mod y2_mod
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1     0   200      1     NA
#> 2     2     0   250      1     NA
#> 3     3     0   200      1     NA
#> 4     8     4   100      2      1
#> 5     9     5    90      2      1
#> 6     0     6    80     NA      1
```